# Is this the right approach for subscriptions in Android with a web service?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, google-play-services

I have a app that is connected to a webservice. I have implemented subscriptions in my app and I am not sure whether it is the right way to do it. Here's what I'm doing.

1. I'm doing a `REQUEST_PURCHASE` with proper id and type.
2. Google Play will respond with async `IN_APP_NOTIFY`.
3. I call `GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION` to get the purchase information.
4. I get `purchaseToken` and other details from `PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED` response. I store them in local DB.
5. I send `CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION` to confirm that I've received the `purchaseToken`.
6. Now I check my local DB and get the `purchaseToken` and send it to my web server which will use Google Developer Android API to verify the purchase and unlock the subscription content. When my server tells the app that it's validated, i remove it from my DB.

And on every start of app I check if my local DB has some entries, and if there are, I try to validate it by calling my webserver again.

I'm doubtful of the 6th step. I think I should confirm with my server first and then do the step 5.

What is the right approach here when there  is a webservice I can make use of?

Comment: I m also worked on Android Subscription in my app i do almost similar like you ask i also not figure out i m right or wrong can you tell me the right way to implement that if u found right way..?

Answer (score 0):

Since there wasn't an answer on this in a long time I decided to write it myself.

V2 in-app billing APIs were insanely complicated. V3 APIs are available for subscription and it's highly recommended to use it. The APIs are super simple to implement.

And from what I've seen, people are more hesitant towards a subscription when compared to one-time purchase. So I moved to one-time purchase model with only one plan that on purchase gives pro features for a year after which they could renew it again.

Flow is quite simple now.

- Request purchase.
- On return of success, show a message like "It may take a couple of minutes for pro features to be activated"
- Consume purchase.
- Store purchaseToken in a local cache.
- Validate with server in background.
- Unlock the pro features.